# Twitter feed HTML

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget, customization

I am trying to display the last 5 tweets in a div, that's about it. I will put a design around it to mimmick the Twitter widget you can get on the Twitter site.

The problem is I am unsure of how to do this. I went through some of the Twitter docs, searched here, found some tutorials. None really seem to cover just this.

Can someone point me in the right direction or shed some light on what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Well it would be handy if you were a bit more specific. If you want a twitter widget...well you could use the twitter widget! What is it that you want?

Comment: "I am trying to display the last 5 tweets in a div, that's about it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might provide you with the source code to get you started. Its the [jQuery Twitter Ticker plugin](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/312/). Here's [another link that is a bit more descriptive](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/jquery-twitter-ticker/).

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch the data
2. Generate DOM elements that match the structure you want, populating them with the data as you go
3. Insert into the DOM for the page
4. Edit your CSS until you're happy with it